# URL mapping in Servlets

Tags: jsp, url, servlets

I am building a site with JSPs and Servlets.
How do I map a URL like this `example.com/12345` so that I get the response as if the request was `example.com/content.jsp?id=12345`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an `url-pattern` of `/*`, gather the pathinfo by [`HttpServletRequest#getPathInfo()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getPathInfo()) and finally forward the request to the desired destination by [`RequestDispatcher#forward()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29).

Basic kickoff example (business logic and exception handling aside):

```
String pathInfo = request.getPathInfo();
String id = pathInfo.substring(1); // Get rid of trailing slash.
String newURL = String.format("/content.jsp?id=%d", id);
request.getRequestDispatcher(newURL).forward(request, response);
```

Alternatively, especially if actually no business logic is involved, you can also use the [Tuckey's UrlRewriteFilter](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) for this. This way you can rewrite your URL's the way as you would do with Apache HTTPD's well known `mod_rewrite`.